# What's the difference between these two definitions of polynomial function?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, definition

Definition 1:
Given $a_n,...,a_1,a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, a polynomial function is a function $p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ such that $p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$

Definition 2: 
The function  $p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial function if there exist $a_n,...,a_1,a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ for any $x$

The first definition is the one I've always used; the second comes from *Linear algebra done right*. Now, I can understand both of them, but I can't see why one would need to complicate matters with the second definition, which seems a little more difficult to me. What's the difference? Why use one or the other?

Comment: The first definition is confusing and strange, it seems to imply that a "polynomial" with different coefficients than the chosen coefficients is not a polynomial.  The second is the standard definition.

Comment: I prefer the second and would like to define the *degree* of the polynomial at the same time; i.e. say something about $a_n$.

Comment: Definition 2 is a more precise way of stating Definition 1. If you think these definitions say different things, then you are misreading one of them (most likely, Definition 1, as it is sloppier).

Comment: Maybe I haven't written def. 1 properly, but I believe there *is* a difference. For example, if you define the degree of a polynomial to be $n$, using definition one it is determined, whereas using definition 2 a polynomial function could have more than one degree (which is not the case, because you can prove that for each polynomial function there is just one set of coefficients, but you can't know it beforehand).

Comment: Nicol, neither definition define the degree of a polynomial, because $a_n$ is not assumed nonzero.  Definition 1 is supposed to say what definition 2 says, but either fails to be clear, or correct, depending on your interpretation.  Just forget definition 1, and use definition 2.

Comment: Seth, I agree that maybe def. 1 is written improperly, because at present I don't have a reference to copy it from, but it definitely does *not* say the same thing as def. 2 (even though I trust that they are equivalent). I'll look for a reference and fix it, but no, I won't just "forget" about it. My aim right now is to understand.

Comment: Is definition 1 your attempt to say something about uniqueness of coefficients?  Because that follows from definition 2, excluding adding higher coefficients that are zero.

Comment: The first definition makes no sense. It's like saying "Given integers $p,q$ with $q \ne 0$, a rational number is $p/q$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't really know what you are trying to say with definition 1, but I suspect you are trying to ensure some sort of uniqueness of coefficients, and apparently define the degree of a polynomial.  I think you missed the mark here, so here is a simple and correct way to define a polynomial, and it's degree.

Define a polynomial of degree $n\geq0$ to be a function $p:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists $a_n,\dots,a_0\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a_n\neq0$ and $p(x)=a_n x^n+\dots a_1 x+ a_0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Define a polynomial of degree $n=-\infty$ to be the zero function.

Define a polynomial to be any function which is a polynomial of degree $n$ for some $n$.

The coefficients are unique in the following sense:  if any function $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $p(x)=a_n x^n+\dots a_1 x+ a_0$ for all $x$ and also $p(x)=b_m x^m+\dots b_1 x+ b_0$ for all $x$, then without loss of generality we may suppose $n\leq m$, and defining $a_i=0$ for $i=n+1,\dots, m$ we may conclude that for $j=0,\dots,m$, $a_j=b_j$.  The uniqueness statement may be proven and is not part of the definition.

Comment: After some reflection I think I understand now. Thank you for your patience.